# Animate CCSprite on Each Update

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, augmented-reality

I have a CCSprite object of which I need to update the on screen (x,y) position as quickly as possible. It is an augmented reality app so the on screen position needs to appear fixed to a real world location.

Currently, during each `update` I check the heading and attitude of the device then move the sprite accordingly by determining the new x and y positions

```
[spriteObject setPosition:ccp(newX, newY)];
```

Each degree change in heading corresponds to 10 pixels in on screen position, so by setting the position this way the sprite jumps around in intervals of 10 pixels which looks stupid. I'd like to animate it smoothly, maybe by using

```
[spriteObject runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2f position:ccp(newX, newY)]];
```

but the problem here is that a new position update comes in while the sprite is animating and it sort of screws the whole thing up. Anyone know of a nice solution to this problem? Any help is much appreciated as I've tried numerous failed solutions to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to just animate your sprite movement to the point. I mean, you can several times during one second run animated position correction with duration of 1/numberOfUpdates in one second. Something like

```
- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self schedule:@selector(updatePositionAnimated) interval:0.2f];

}

- (void) updatePositionAnimated
{
    [spriteObject runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2f position:ccp(newX, newY)]];
}
```

I suppose, you will have smooth enough animation in this case